# What happened to "too localized" close-vote reason?

Tags: support

I just attempted to [close this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104510/how-to-add-jquery-script-to-an-individual-page) as "too localized", only to discover that the option is no longer available. Where did that option go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The War of the Closes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1)

> “Off-Topic” now includes site-specific close reasons
>
> [...]
>
> These site-specific reasons will also address situations previously covered by “General Reference” and “Too Localized”. Those were the least used and most misused reasons – moderator and team sampling found a huge percentage of their application to be erroneous.

Comment: I wish there was a bit more exposure than just a blog post when infrastructural changes are made. We get lots of notices; why can't we get notices for system changes such as this one?

Comment: @ChipBennett a lot of it would be uninteresting to most users I think, those who care just subscribe to the blog (those who really care stalk [changelog on global meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/163749))